# Exists Many to many Relationship

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm using Amazon Redshift, and can't get a query right. Suppose I have a lot of projects that each require one or more skills. So there's a many-to-many relationship between projects and skills. Users create projects, so there's one creator per project.

For each project, I want to get all of the other projects by the same creator that shares at least one skill. So I'd like to write something like this:

```
SELECT p1.project_id, p2.project_id
FROM projects p1 
JOIN projects p2 on p1.creator = p2.creator
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 0
              from skills sk1, skills sk2 
              where sk1.project_id = p1.project_id 
                and sk2.project_id = p2.project_id 
                and sk1.skill = sk2.skill)
```

Problem is that this is REALLY (gives a `disk full` error).

The following works, but is also really slow (takes half an hour or so):

```
SELECT distinct p1.project_id, p2.project_id
FROM projects p1
  JOIN projects p2 on p1.creator = p2.creator
  join skills sk1 on sk1.project_id = p1.project_id
  join skills sk2 on sk2.project_id = p2.project_id
WHERE sk1.skill = sk2.skill
```

Problem with this one is that if I want to aggregate some properties on the second project, I have to use this as a subquery.

Is there a better way to do this? I would've thought the first query would be faster since it stops at picking out a single project.

Comment: Do you have any indices setup on the join columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple problem with your query is that you are allowing projects to join to themselves.  This means that every single project will be returned.

Fix it by ensuring the two projects being joined are not the same:

```
JOIN projects p2 on 
   p1.creator = p2.creator and
   p2.project_id > p1.project_id
```

Note that I used `>` rather than `!=` so that two matching projects only join in one direction.  Otherwise each pair of projects will be returned twice.

Your join-based solution would then be something like this:

```
SELECT distinct p1.project_id, p2.project_id
   FROM projects p1
   JOIN projects p2 on 
      p1.creator = p2.creator and
      p2.project_id > p1.project_id
   join skills sk1 on 
      sk1.project_id = p1.project_id
   join skills sk2 on 
      sk2.project_id = p2.project_id and
      sk1.skill = sk2.skill
```